# Android button select and press drawable

Tags: android, button, styles, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I'm trying to make a button with state press and select,
I already did the same with tabs and it works but I don't know why here does not work.
 I have done it like this:

button_sel.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/azulado" 
              android:endColor="@color/azulBrillante"
              android:angle="270" />
     <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
     <stroke android:width="2px" 
             android:color="@color/blanco" />
 </shape>
```

button_unsel.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/botonesD" 
              android:endColor="@color/botones"
              android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
    <stroke android:width="2px" 
            android:color="@color/blanco" />
</shape>
```

And the selector, button.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel"  
          android:state_selected="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_unsel" 
      android:state_selected="false" 
      android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

And here I call the drawable as a background:

```
 <style name="button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/padding_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blanco</item>
 </style>
```

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The first item in your selector is only used, when the button is pressed AND selected. If you want to use `button_sel` when your button is pressed OR selected, you should do something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_unsel" />
</selector>
```

The items are evaluated from top to bottom, the last one is the default. Though I am not sure if state_selected makes sense for buttons.

Answer (score 12):

Can use shape inline item.

```
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true" >
            <shape....>
        </item>
        <item android:state_selected="true" >
            <shape....>
        </item>
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true" >
            <shape...>
        </item>
   </selector>
```

For sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/md_amber_300"
                android:endColor="@color/md_amber_50"
                android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/fab_margin" />
            <stroke android:width="2px"
                android:color="@color/primaryColorDark_orange" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/md_amber_300"
                android:endColor="@color/md_amber_50"
                android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/fab_margin" />
            <stroke android:width="2px"
                android:color="@color/primaryColorDark_orange" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:startColor="@color/md_teal_500"
                android:endColor="@color/md_blue_400"
                android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/fab_margin" />
            <stroke android:width="2px"
                android:color="@color/md_amber_A400" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```