# Spinner click effect can't include the view inside

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm developing an android app.

I use customize Spinner to do selecting.

I face a problem, that is when I press the Spinner, the custom view inside the Spinner

seems can't be selected.

I want the effect can include all the stuff inside, not just outside of the Spinner.

like

[image]

the xml:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/calendars_spinner"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"/>
```

the getView of Spinner adapter

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_spinner_item, parent,
                false);
        CalendarGroup group = groups.get(position);
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(group.getColor());

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_name);
        if (name != null) {
            String displayName = group.getGroupName();
            name.setText(displayName);

            TextView accountName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.account_name);
            if (accountName != null) {
                accountName.setText(mEvent.getOwner());
                accountName.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
        convertView.setTag(position);
        return convertView;
    }
```

the view inside (calendar_spinner_item.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/calendar_name"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/account_name"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/calendar_name"
    android:layout_below="@id/calendar_name"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:
`convertView.setBackgroundColor(group.getColor());`

add to it selectable drawable:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:backround="@drawable/some_selectable_drawable>
```

And this is what drawable should be alike:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_sel"
        android:state_selected="true" 
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_unsel" 
        android:state_selected="false" 
        android:state_pressed="false"/>
</selector>
```

Or maybe at first just try to remove this #setBackgroundColor call and see what will happen.

Hope it helps

Reference: [Android button select and press drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443534/android-button-select-and-press-drawable)