# Image button is not clickable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/send_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/send_button_foreground"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

**Image button is not clickable although I am using a background XML, still it's showing error**
XML code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size android:width="55dp"
                android:height="55dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#10A597"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Could you please share your java or kotlin codes?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error, it's running fine though, but it's not clickable that's it

Comment: [link] http://p.ip.fi/2-1l [link] of java code. It's just emmpty

Comment: add click listener on the imageView to make it clickable

Comment: What you have is right, it's working fine but, the animation of clickable is not being shown when it is clicked. http://p.ip.fi/H6J8 this is the code. Is there any clickable attribute that is set to be true or like that!!

Comment: When I remove the background its again showing the clickable animation

Comment: for clickable animation and background both, you can use SelectableDrawable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443534/android-button-select-and-press-drawable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add on click property in side imageButton

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_x="312dp"
    android:layout_y="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:background="@drawable/search" />
```

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
ImageButton imageButton3;

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        imageButton3=findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        imageButton3.setOnClickListener(this);

}
      @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.imageButton3:
             //do something..  
        break;
    }
}

}
```